# how to append multiple values to an associative array?

Tags: php

I have to append more values to the associative array, the values are getting overwritten and I can see only last value displayed.

My snippet is :

```
$sql= "SELECT  MONTHNAME(dt),SUM(dist) FROM demo GROUP BY MONTHNAME(dt) ";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$values=array($row['MONTHNAME(dt)'] => $row['SUM(dist)']);

}
```

I expect other values also to be present the array $values, but it is not happening.

Comment: Then what about if you actually *appended to the array* instead of *overwriting the variable*?!

Comment: @Svetlio Oh no, that'll actually work here.

Comment: @Svetlio OP can. It is aliases already.

Comment: Hint: `$values[] = ...`

Comment: deceze, it's clear that he wants to use a specific key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem you need to do something like this,

```
$values = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $values[$row['MONTHNAME(dt)']] = $row['SUM(dist)'];
}
print_r($values);
```

If you need an associative array than do like.

```
$values[] = array($row['MONTHNAME(dt)'] => $row['SUM(dist)']);
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: `$row['SUM(dist)']);` < brace ?

Comment: no its not like this, i have to store month name with total distance run in the month. For this i will need associative array.with the code:$values=array($row['MONTHNAME(dt)'] => $row['SUM(dist)']);   i am able to store the values but it is showing me the last stored values only...i want the values of all the months which is there in my database..

Comment: @ShivaniSinha - yes . you can do either way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$values[$row['MONTHNAME(dt)']] = $row['SUM(dist)']
```

Comment: Please, consider usage of highlight options, when posting code.

Comment: I figured the purpose of highlighting was to distinguish code from not code. This the post had ONLY code, what is the purpose of highlighting? edit: I suppose there's also syntax coloring now

Comment: to make code **readable**.

Comment: the only difference from before and now is that the key is red.

Comment: is it more readable? _(spoiler) colors is metadata for reader (/spolier)_

Comment: no, in my opinion, this single line of code is not more readable than it was before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use.

```
$sql= "SELECT  MONTHNAME(dt),SUM(dist) FROM demo GROUP BY MONTHNAME(dt) ";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
$values = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

  $values[] = array($row['MONTHNAME(dt)'] => $row['SUM(dist)']);

}
```